# Apply function to each element to generate sequence with yield in F#

Tags: f#, sequence, yield

I am relative new with F# and one of the more complicate things to me is how to use yield properly.
I am trying to generate a sequence by reading a text file and extracting for each line the values with a and add them into a sequence(the result)

**regexp function** from http://www.fssnip.net/29/title/Regular-expression-active-pattern

```
let (|Regex|_|) pattern input =
    let m = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
    if m.Success then Some(List.tail [ for g in m.Groups -> g.Value ])
    else None

let extractCoordinates input =
    match input with
    | Regex @"\(([0-9]{3})\)[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})" [ area; prefix; suffix ] ->
        [ area; prefix; suffix ]
    | _ -> []
```

**read file and generate sequence**

```
open System.IO

let filepath = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"../../test_input_01.txt"

let values =
        File.ReadAllLines 
        |> Seq.map (fun l -> extractCoordinates l)
```

but it is no working

> error FS0001: The type 'string -> string []' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'

Could anyone tell me how to apply a function to each element of a list and store the output into a sequence result? Using `yield` or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with `Seq.map` is correct. The error you get is from not providing the argument to `File.ReadAllLines`:

```
let values =
    File.ReadAllLines filepath
    |> Seq.map (fun l -> extractCoordinates l)
```